# alguna idea de como poder sacar estas filas de una tabla SQLITe?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Alguna idea de como poder sacar los datos de la columna total, pero q estos datos coincidan con los datos de las filas "Transferencia"?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo sacar las "Transferencia" por media de este Script

```
SELECT forma_pago  from reporte_cuadre where forma_pago = "Transferencia"
```

pero no encuentro la forma de sacarlo junto con su fila en total, osea:

```
forma_pago     total
Transferencia  1500
Transferencia  7650
                                  Gracias x la ayuda.
```

Comment: `SELECT forma_pago, total  from reporte_cuadre where forma_pago = "Transferencia"`?

Comment: gracias.! funciono bastante bien, y yo sufriendo.!  ponlo como comentario respuesta para seleccionarla como respuesta. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes seleccionar también la columna de total para que quede en los resultados:

```
SELECT forma_pago, total  from reporte_cuadre where forma_pago = "Transferencia"
```